# Multiple object animations not exporting to GLB

Tags: animation, export

New to GLB export.
I am trying to export multiple objects, each of which is animated separately.
Currently both the objects export but only one animation.

I am already aware of this:

> glTF allows multiple animations per file, with animations targeted to
> particular objects at time of export. To ensure that an animation is
> included, either (a) make it the active Action on the object, (b)
> create a single-strip NLA track, or (c) stash the action.

I have already tried pushing the actions down in the NLA editor (and *importantly* naming them the same) and also stashing them.
[image: Animations Pushed down and named the same in NLA editor]
Neither of these solutions worked.

Any further suggestions or help would be massively appreciated.
Thanks in advance,

LJ

Comment: Share the .blend.

Answer (score 4):

Solved! The NLA tracks needed to be named the same, not the action strips. Also they can't be left with the default names - although they may be the same. The NLA tracks have to be renamed to identical names.

Comment: Can't thank you enough for this! This solved my issue!
WTF this is so confusing

Comment: Ok, I will try this, as I've been looking for a way to export multiple animations into the same .gltf from Blender, but nothing has worked so far. I only get the 1st frame of the 1st animation. I am working with Blender 3 experimental and exporting .gltf with .bin